# Using of variable in nested IF ELSE (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement

I have a problem in using of array as a variable in nested if..else.. conditions. Its used to create custom web-service APIs. Here is the structure of code:

```
if (condition) {
    // code to be executed in case of true

    if (condition) {
        // code to be executed in case of true

        $result['key1'] = $variable1;
        $result['key2'] = $variable2;
        $result['key3'] = $variable3;

    } else {
        // code to be executed in case of false
    }

} else {
    $result['error'] = 'Something went wrong!!!';
}
echo json_encode($result);    // line 121
```

On execution of code it displays the following error:

**Notice:** Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp.. on line 121

Comment: Define your variable before checking.

Comment: If both of your if conditions are false, you will get that notice. Simply initialize your `$result` array before your first `if`

Comment: Define $result and $variable1 before checking thus outside if

Answer (score 0):

Variables need to be declared before using it inside functions like [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)! Do it this way:

```
$result = array();
if (condition) {
    // code to be executed in case of true

    if (condition) {
        // code to be executed in case of true

        $result['key1'] = $variable1;
        $result['key2'] = $variable2;
        $result['key3'] = $variable3;

    } else {
        // code to be executed in case of false
    }

} else {
    $result['error'] = 'Something went wrong!!!';
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to declare your variable first if you are directly entering the value to an array.

```
$result = array();

if (condition) {
    // code to be executed in case of true

    if (condition) {
        // code to be executed in case of true

        $result['key1'] = $variable1;
        $result['key2'] = $variable2;
        $result['key3'] = $variable3;

    } else {
        // code to be executed in case of false
    }

} else {
    $result['error'] = 'Something went wrong!!!';
}
echo json_encode($result);    // line 121
```

Comment: use a upvote rather giving same